# Biasing phototransistor for homemade Reflectance sensor

Tags: sensor, phototransistor

I need a reflectance sensor like the TCRT5000 for a project I'm doing. The sensor should detect the transition from a dark surface to a white surface.

I have infrared LEDs and phototransistors and would like to use them to build the sensor so as to not spend more money and time.

I have however some difficulties in understanding the biasing of the phototransistor.

I know this should be the general look of the biasing circuit:

[image]

<sub>Image source: [QTR-1A Reflectance Sensor](https://www.pololu.com/product/2458)</sub>

I understand that the big pullup resistor on the right has its value set by subtracting VCE(sat) from VCC and dividing the voltage drop by the collector current through the phototransistor when the irradiance has a certain value.

The radiant intensity of the IR beam is very high, 50mW/sr at 20mA. Presuming the maximum distance between the sensor and the detectable surface is 1cm, the irradiance will be 50mW/cm2 which is completely outside the bounds of the phototransistor characteristic, which maxes out its current capability at 1mW/cm2.

**Where is the mistake in this? Should I multiply the irradiance by the "radiant sensitive area"? Should I drive the IR LED at very low currents to decrease the radiant intensity?**

Additionally, given that the light from the IR LED is reflected back to the phototransistor should the irradiance be 1/2 of the irradiance at the point it touches the detectable surface?

Datasheets for phototransistor and IR LED:

- [OSRAM SFH 300 FA](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2711609.pdf)
- [Kodenshi KCL5587S](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1993613.pdf)

Comment: To lower the sensitivity increase IR Led resistor or decrease the transistor resistor. I would certainly decrease the IR Led current to lower the power consumption.

Comment: If you have the parts already, just try it. You can reduce the LED current to maybe 10mA and maybe decrease the 47K to 10kΩ or 20kΩ but I suspect you'll be in the right ballpark with 20mm round trip and some unknown reflectance etc. You will not hurt the phototransistor. You might pick up too much light from the 'dark' surface though.

Comment: So the imbalance between the radiant intensity of the LED and the irradiance range of the phototransistor is a real thing and not a misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't think there's much imbalance when you take into account the amount of light that actually makes it back and hits the tiny phototransistor die.

Comment: If the surface was very reflective most of the light would in my mind still reach the phototransistor. I guess my best course of action would be to significantly lower the current through the LED and tweak the values of the resistors. I would also be worried that the transistor would not be saturated as I cannot really measure VBE and compare it to VCE like the usual.

Comment: I know the datasheet mentions that the typical VCE(sat) is 140mV for IC = IPCE(min) * 0.3 and Ee = 0.5mW/cm2. IPCE(min) doesn't have very clear values and Ee will vary wildly. And I would very much like to keep the transistor saturated at all times. So perhaps I should take a very low Ee and compute the value of the pull up resistor such that the phototransistor turns on.